# dotCMS 2.5.6 can't start after JDK update from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: java, tomcat, dotcms

I've updated JDK from 1.7 to 1.8 on a Red Hat machine.

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

After rebuild my `dotCMS 2.5.6` installation the application can't start anymore with the following errors reported by `dotcms.log` file

```
FATAL util.FileUtil: Config.CONTEXT not initialized with a servlet context, dying
INFO filters.CharsetEncodingFilter: Destroying character encoding filter...
INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Shutdown event received, executing a clean shutdown.
ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the Schedulers.
WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)
```

I've tried to update tomcat `context.xml` file with no success, and have no idea on where I can look for the root cause of these errors.

**DETAILED LOG**

**dotcms.log**

```
[17/11/20 08:09:47:290 CET]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: contextInitialized - Register BeanUtilsBean ConvertUtils prefs.
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                            7777777   7777       7777     77777777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                 OO       777777777  77777      77777    77777777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                OOO      77777       777777     77777   7777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOOO 7777         7777777   777777   7777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO  OOOOO  OOOO  OOOO    OOOO    7777         7777777  7777777    777777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         77777777 777 7777     777777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO OOOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         777  777 777 7777        7777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    77777        777  777777  7777         7777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO   OOOO  OOOO   OOO    OOOO     77777       777   7777   7777        7777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO      OOOOO    777777777  777   7777   7777  777777777
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                          Content Management System
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:47:329 CET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                
[17/11/20 08:09:48:330 CET]  INFO util.Config: Initializing properties reader.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:330 CET]  INFO util.Config: Loading dotCMS Properties...
[17/11/20 08:09:48:347 CET]  INFO util.Config: Assigned default refresh interval: 5 minutes.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:347 CET]  INFO util.Config: dotCMS Properties Loaded
[17/11/20 08:09:48:348 CET]  INFO listeners.OsgiFelixListener: OSGI Disabled
[17/11/20 08:09:48:350 CET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
[17/11/20 08:09:48:362 CET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:362 CET]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: com.dotcms.enterprise.cmis.server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl
[17/11/20 08:09:48:389 CET]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/system.properties
[17/11/20 08:09:48:389 CET]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/system-ext.properties
[17/11/20 08:09:48:401 CET]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/portal.properties
[17/11/20 08:09:48:402 CET]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
[17/11/20 08:09:48:408 CET]  INFO filters.XssFilter: XssFilter initialization.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:408 CET]  INFO filters.XssFilter: ESAPIValidation: false
[17/11/20 08:09:48:408 CET]  INFO filters.XssFilter: Path to exclude from XSS sanitization: [[EXT_LUCENE_TOOL, EXT_LANG]]
[17/11/20 08:09:48:466 CET]  INFO business.CacheLocator: loading cache administrator: com.dotmarketing.business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl
[17/11/20 08:09:48:473 CET]  INFO business.ESDistributedJournalFactoryImpl: Server IDs configured: [1]
[17/11/20 08:09:48:474 CET]  INFO util.ConfigUtils: Using configured hostname: 1
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : default: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workingcache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : adminconfigpool: 100
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorybykeycache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorycache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categorychildrencache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : companypool: 10
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmslayoutcache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsrolecache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsrolekeycache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : dotcmsuserrolecache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : fieldscache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : filecache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : languagecacheimpl: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : plugincache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : portletpool: 100
[17/11/20 08:09:48:549 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : structurecache: 500
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : templatecache: 500
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : userdotcmscache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : useremaildotcmscache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : userproxycache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitymenucache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitymisscache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowcache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowtaskcache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : indiciescache: 8
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : logmappercache: 10
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : livecache: 5000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : blockdirectivecache: 2000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : categoryparentscache: 5000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : contentletcache: 15000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : fileassetmetadatacache: 20000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : foldercache: 10000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostaliascache: 100
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostcache: 100
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : hostvariablescache: 100
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : htmlpagecache: 2000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : identifiercache: 50000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : navcache: 2000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : parentpermissionablecache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : permissioncache: 20000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : publishingendpointcache: 0
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : translatedquerycache: 20000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : velocitycache: 4000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : versioncache: 20000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : versioninfocache: 20000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : virtuallinkscache: 2000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowactioncache: 1000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   Cache Config Memory : workflowstepcache: 2000
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   cache_default_ttl : 5
[17/11/20 08:09:48:550 CET]  INFO business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl: ***   record_guava_stats : false
[17/11/20 08:09:48:686 CET] FATAL util.FileUtil: Config.CONTEXT not initialized with a servlet context, dying
[17/11/20 08:09:48:691 CET]  INFO filters.CharsetEncodingFilter: Destroying character encoding filter...
[17/11/20 08:09:48:692 CET]  INFO listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: Shutdown event received, executing a clean shutdown.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:702 CET] ERROR listeners.ContextLifecycleListener: A error ocurred trying to shutdown the Schedulers.
[17/11/20 08:09:48:704 CET]  WARN reindex.ReindexThread: ReindexThread not running (or already shutting down)
```

**catalina.out**

```
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.593 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve} Setting property 'resolveHosts' to 'false' did not find a matching propert                      y.
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 23 2015 11:56:07 UTC
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.18.0
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_212-b04
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/conf/logging.properties
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xverify:none
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1G
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/dotCMS/WEB-INF/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Ddotserver=dotcms_nsi_nop
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/endorsed
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/temp
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the ja                      va.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.715 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.734 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 500 ms
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.756 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.756 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
17-Nov-2020 08:09:37.776 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jcl-1.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/../../dotCMS/WEB-INF/lib/tika-app-1.7mod.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.690 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error filterStart
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.690 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.716 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.718 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.718 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.719 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.720 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.721 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.721 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.722 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Log4J Active Asynchronous Appender] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.locks.CondVar.await(CondVar.java:72)
 edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:401)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventBlockingDeque.takeLast(LoggingEventBlockingDeque.java:80)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.dispatchAndWait(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:242)
 org.apache.log4j.appender.LoggingEventDispatcher.run(LoggingEventDispatcher.java:91)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.732 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /var/dotcms_nsi_nop/tomcat-8.0.18/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml has finished in 10,956 ms
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.734 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Nov-2020 08:09:48.739 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 11002 ms
```

Comment: Please show us the stacktraces.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've included a detailed log section with both docms.log and catalina.out reports.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging deeper, I am pretty sure dotCMS 2.5.6 requires java 1.7 and does not run on java 1.8.

Comment: Do you think is not possible to use java 1.8 in order to update also tomcat to version 8?
If it could be possible with some modification it would be ok.

Comment: I think you either need to downgrade your java to 1.7 or upgrade your dotCMS version to a version that support Java 1.8